# What is the mathematical logic behind the arithmetic operations used in the equation of the Z-score; (X- mu)/ (sigma)?

Tags: probability-theory, recreational-mathematics, mathematical-modeling

I understood that naturally occurring phenomenon such a weight of all individuals form a bell curved normal distribution, with more frequency applied to the center. but I'm confused with the arithmetic operators used to derive the Z-score of the standard normal distribution.

Say, I found the mean weight of a population to around 60kg and to convert to standard normal distribution I first subtracted the individual weight/random measure by the mean i.e. with 60kg but then moving on why are we dividing it by (sigma) the standard deviation to find distance of how far the data point is away from the mean. Why did we use the arithmetic operation of division and why divide with sigma (the standard deviation) to find the Z-score? Can someone help out to conceptualize the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice property of normal distributions, namely that if $Z$ is standard normal, then any linear function of $Z$ is normal:

$$Z\sim N(0,1)\implies X=\sigma Z+\mu\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2).$$

Reversing this tells us that if $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$,
$$\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\sim N(0,1).$$

Thus, we can compute probabilities involving any normal random variable  $X$ in terms of a standard normal just by *standardizing* $X$:

$$P(a<X<b)=P\left(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}<\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}<\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}\right)=P\left(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}<Z<\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}\right)$$

where $Z\sim N(0,1).$

Comment: thanks for the info @Golden_Ratio , i'll research on the property to get a better grip.

Comment: @Charles ok happy to help. You could also take the property as a *definition* of what it means to be a general normal random variable. But if you define normality in some other way (e.g. using densities), it is a property.